Concurrent reads alongside overwrites in Azure Blob storage
We have some functions which will be pretty much continually reading various files from blob storage, while other processes update them on some other triggers behind the scenes.
We are currently using the C# equivalent of put blob which states that it will overwrite an existing blob:

The Put Blob operation creates a new block, page, or append blob, or updates the content of an existing block blob. The Put Blob operation will overwrite all contents of an existing blob with the same name.
When you update an existing block blob, you overwrite any existing metadata on the blob. The content of the existing blob is overwritten with the content of the new blob.

Which is exactly what we want, but how exactly does it perform this? If it deletes the existing blob, then creates an empty 'file', then uploads the new content, there is a concurrency issue here where another process will attempt to read the existing blob and either see it missing, or see an empty/partially uploaded file.
I want any other process to be able to read the old version, right up until the moment that the new one is ready, and then switch to seeing the new one - with zero downtime inbetween.
I thought about using leases but the way these work I'd need to acquire a lease on every single read, and that lease would block other reads and the write completely, so performance would be terrible.
Is there any other mechanism I can use to get this functionality? Or have I misunderstood what put blob is doing behind the scenes?

If you are concerned about concurrency issues, you can use blob versioning to maintain multiple versions of the same blob. This allows you to read the old version while the new version is being uploaded. Once the new version is fully uploaded, you can switch to the new version.


Is there any other mechanism I can use to get this functionality? Or have I misunderstood what put blob is doing behind the scenes?

According to this MS-Document,

The Put Blob operation does not delete the existing blob and then create an empty file.
Instead, it overwrites the existing blob with the new content. This means that any other process that is reading the old version will continue to see the old version until the new one is fully uploaded. Once the new version is fully uploaded, any subsequent reads will see the new version.

To achieve these processes can read the old version of a blob up until the moment a new version is fully uploaded you can use the concept of blob versioning or snapshots.
If you want to maintain multiple versions of the same blob, you can use blob versioning. To enable blob versioning, you need to set the IsVersioningEnabled property of the storage account to true
You can use this below command to enable blob versioning.
Command and output:
venkatesan [ ~ ]$ az storage account blob-service-properties update  --resource-group xxxx --account-name xxxx --enable-versioning true
{
  "automaticSnapshotPolicyEnabled": null,
  "changeFeed": null,
  "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
    "allowPermanentDelete": null,
    "days": null,
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cors": {
    "corsRules": [
      {
        "allowedHeaders": [
          "*"
        ],
        "allowedMethods": [
          "DELETE",
          "GET",
          "HEAD",
          "MERGE",
          "POST",
          "OPTIONS",
          "PUT",
          "PATCH"
        ],
        "allowedOrigins": [
          "*"
        ],
        "exposedHeaders": [
          "*"
        ],
        "maxAgeInSeconds": xxx
      },
      {
        "allowedHeaders": [
          "*"
        ],
        "allowedMethods": [
          "GET",
          "OPTIONS"
        ],
        "allowedOrigins": [
          "xxx"
        ],
        "exposedHeaders": [
          "*"
        ],
        "maxAgeInSeconds": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  "defaultServiceVersion": null,
  "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
    "allowPermanentDelete": false,
    "days": null,
    "enabled": false
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xx/blobServices/default",
  "isVersioningEnabled": true,
  "lastAccessTimeTrackingPolicy": {
    "blobType": null,
    "enable": true,
    "name": null,
    "trackingGranularityInDays": null
  },
  "name": "default",
  "resourceGroup": "xxxxx",
  "restorePolicy": null,
  "sku": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"
}


Reference:

Blob versioning - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
Blob snapshots - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

